# Javascript on a desktop wallpaper (XP)

Tags: windows-xp

I have a desktop wallpaper shipped out by my domain, it's a HTML wallpaper that displays information like today's date, etc.

It also has the internet usage rules. Using jquery I've made it so that the rules are hidden and displayed when you click on the section heading.

The JS runs fine and it hides the rules, but it appears that once the desktop "loses focus" the javascript stops and clicking the headings does nothing.

Anyone know a way to keep javascript running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never got anywhere with this but because Windows 7 no longer supports HTML wallpapers I don't see any point progressing this.

Answer (score 0):

I use a jQuery Wallpaper on my Virtual Windows xp machine and it works fine even when it looses Focus , I use IE6 on that machine .

May be your script is designed in such a way check it once again .

What version of IE do you have because the desktop wallpaper is rendered by the Internet Explorer Engine !!